# Using binary_crossentropy loss in Keras (Tensorflow backend)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In the training example in Keras documentation,

https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#training

**binary_crossentropy** is used and **sigmoid** activation is added in the network's last layer, but is it necessary that add **sigmoid** in the last layer? As I found in the source code:

```
def binary_crossentropy(output, target, from_logits=False):
  """Binary crossentropy between an output tensor and a target tensor.
  Arguments:
      output: A tensor.
      target: A tensor with the same shape as `output`.
      from_logits: Whether `output` is expected to be a logits tensor.
          By default, we consider that `output`
          encodes a probability distribution.
  Returns:
      A tensor.
  """
  # Note: nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
  # expects logits, Keras expects probabilities.
  if not from_logits:
    # transform back to logits
    epsilon = _to_tensor(_EPSILON, output.dtype.base_dtype)
    output = clip_ops.clip_by_value(output, epsilon, 1 - epsilon)
    output = math_ops.log(output / (1 - output))
  return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
```

Keras invokes **sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits** in Tensorflow, but in **sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits** function, **sigmoid(logits)** is calculated again.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

So I don't think it makes sense that add a **sigmoid** at last, but seemingly all the binary/multi-label classification examples and tutorials in Keras I found online added **sigmoid** at last. Besides I don't understand what is the meaning of

```
# Note: nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
# expects logits, Keras expects probabilities.
```

Why Keras expects probabilities? Doesn't it use the **nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits** function? Does it make sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, that's exactly what's happening. I believe this is due to historical reasons.

Keras was created before tensorflow, as a wrapper around theano. And in theano, one has to compute sigmoid/softmax manually and then apply cross-entropy loss function. Tensorflow does everything in one fused op, but the API with sigmoid/softmax layer was already adopted by the community.

If you want to avoid unnecessary logit <-> probability conversions, call `binary_crossentropy` loss with`from_logits=True` and don't add the sigmoid layer.

Comment: not only in Theano, the same logic is in Torch / PyTorch and I find this to be quite intuitive than TF mess

Comment: Theano doesn't actually force you to use the wrong implementation of cross-entropy. It's purely a Keras design decision. Frameworks based on Theano that pre-dated Keras actually got it right. See for example the pylearn2 implementation: https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/expr/nnet.py#L219

Comment: I had to add a comment here. I just could not believe when I saw @IanGoodfellow ! The Godfather, the Creator of GANs himself ! Amem !

Answer (score 2):

In categorical cross entropy :

- if it is `prediction` it will compute the `cross entropy` directly
- if it is `logit` it will apply `softmax_cross entropy with logit`

In Binary cross entropy:

- if it is `prediction` it will convert it back to `logit` then apply `sigmoied cross entropy with logit`
- if it is `logit` it will apply `sigmoied cross entropy with logit`directly

Answer (score 2):

In Keras by default we use activation sigmoid on the output layer and then use the keras binary_crossentropy loss function, independent of the backend implementation (Theano, Tensorflow or CNTK).

If you look more in depth for the pure Tensorflow case you find that the tensorflow backend binary_crossentropy function (which you pasted in your question) uses tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits. The later function also add the sigmoid activation. To avoid double sigmoid, the tensorflow backend binary_crossentropy, will by default (with from_logits=False) calculate the inverse sigmoid (logit(x)=log(x/1-x)) to get the output back into the raw state from the network with no activation.

The extra activation sigmoid, and inverse sigmoid calculation can be avoided by using no sigmoid activation function in your last layer, and then call the tensorflow backend binary_crossentropy with parameter from_logits=True (Or directly use  tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits)