# What should I use as target vector when I use BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True) in tensorflow.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I have a multi-label classification in which each target is a vector of ones and zeros **not** mutually exclusive (for the sake of clarity, my target is something like `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ... ]`).

My understanding so far is:

- I should use a binary cross-entropy function. (as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175655/4690023))
- Also, I understood that `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()` is a wrapper around tensorflow's `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`. This can be used either with `from_logits` `True` or `False`. (as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741878/using-binary-crossentropy-loss-in-keras-tensorflow-backend))
- Since `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` performs itself the sigmoid, it expects the input to be in the [-inf,+inf] range.
- `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()`, when the network implements
  itself a sigmoid activation of the last layer, must be used with `from_logits=False`. It will then infert the sigmoid function and pass the output to `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` that will do the sigmoid again. This however can cause numerical issues due to the asymptotes of the sigmoid/logit function.
- To improve the numerical stability, we can avoid the last sigmoid layer and use `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)`

Question:

If we use `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)`, what target should I use? Do I need to change my target for the one-hot vector?

I suppose that I should apply then a sigmoid activation to the network output at inference time. Is there a way to add a sigmoid layer active only in inference mode and not in training mode?

Comment: "This however can cause numerical issues due to the asymptotes of the sigmoid/logit function." Can you provide a source for this, please? And further, I don't think just using a sigmoid layer and the simple `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', ...)` would bring any issues. Lots of models have been trained this way without any problems!

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy "Note: Using from_logits=True may be more numerically stable."

Comment: That's not a common problem in this specific case. Let me put it this way: have you encountered this specific problem (i.e. convergence problems due to numerical instability of `from_logits=False` in cross-entropy loss function) in your experiments? If not, then you should not over-think it too much.

Comment: This is another source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125924/why-does-sigmoid-crossentropy-of-keras-tensorflow-have-low-precision

Comment: I agree with you that overthinking is usually bad, but if I can improve the learning of a model just removing the final activation layer and adding an optional parameter to the loss, why shouldn't I?

Comment: While googling right now I found this interesting analysis https://towardsdatascience.com/sigmoid-activation-and-binary-crossentropy-a-less-than-perfect-match-b801e130e31 It basically sais "yes, it COULD give numerical instability, but in practice it never happens"

Comment: I know that (the author of the answer to that question happens to be me!). But as you can see there, it does not produce any **serious issue** for **practical applications** since the difference is so tiny. Anyways, I am not an expert in that area and maybe I am the one who is underthinking! Maybe someone else has a more established opinion.

Comment: "(the author of the answer to that question happens to be me!)" ... ops :P

Comment: If the rest I said is correct and you want to turn this comment in a short answer I will accept it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, let me give some notes about the numerical stability:

As mentioned in the comments section, the numerical instability in case of using `from_logits=False` comes from the transformation of probability values back into logits which involves a clipping operation (as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52125924/2099607) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52126567/2099607)). However, to the best of my knowledge, this does NOT create any **serious issues** for **most of practical applications** (although, there are some cases where applying the softmax/sigmoid function inside the loss function, i.e. using `from_logits=True`, would be more numerically stable in terms of computing gradients; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34917052/2099607) for a mathematical explanation).

In other words, if you are not concerned with precision of generated probability values with sensitivity of less than 1e-7, **or a related convergence issue observed in your experiments**, then you should not worry too much; just use the sigmoid and binary cross-entropy as before, i.e. `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', ...)`, and it would work fine.

All in all, if you are really concerned with numerical stability, you can take the safest path and use `from_logits=True` without using any activation function on the last layer of the model.

---

Now, to answer the original question, the true labels or target values (i.e. `y_true`) should be still only zeros or ones when using `BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`. Rather, that's the `y_pred` (i.e. the output of the model) which should not be a probability distribution in this case (i.e. the sigmoid function should not be used on the last layer if `from_logits=True`).

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I tested GAN on recovering realistic image from sketch and the only difference between two train cycles was BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True/False). Last network layer is Conv2D with no activation, so the right choice should be from_logits=True, but for experimental purposes - I found huge difference in generator and discriminator loss

- orange - True,
- blue - False.

Here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u6dahL5aDoco9c4VnxxpXc_5Q3LpvH_X?usp=sharing) to collab notebook.
Exercise based on [Tensorflow tutorial pix2pix](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix#training).

[image: loss difference between two runs]

According to exercise description if from_logits=True

- The value log(2) = 0.69 is a good reference point for these losses, as it indicates a perplexity of 2: That the discriminator is on average equally uncertain about the two options.
- For the disc_loss a value below 0.69 means the discriminator is doing better than random, on the combined set of real+generated images.
- For the gen_gan_loss a value below 0.69 means the generator i doing better than random at foolding the descriminator.

Otherwise loss twice higher for both: generator and discriminator. SImilar explanation doesn't look to hold relevance anymore.

Final images are also different:

- In case of from_logits==False , image looks blurry and non-realistic
  [image]

Comment: Awesome! Can you plot the difference between the two final image versions?