# Why is computing the loss from logits more numerically stable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cross-entropy

In TensorFlow the documentation for [SparseCategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) states that using `from_logits=True` and therefore excluding the softmax operation in the last model layer is more numerically stable for the loss calculation.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but I think the numerical stability has something to do with precision of floats and overflows.

Say you want to calculate `np.exp(2000)`, it gives you an overflow error. However, calculating `np.log(np.exp(2000))` can be simplified to `2000`.

By using logits you can circumvent large numbers in intermediate steps, avoiding overflows and low precision.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233425/what-should-i-use-as-target-vector-when-i-use-binarycrossentropyfrom-logits-tru/61237426#61237426) I think a good explanation about should you worry about numerical stability or not. Check this answer but in general most likely you should not care about it.

To answer your question "Why is this the case?" let's take a look on [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5a7a789ee9766b6a594bd4be8b9edb34e71d6500/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3219):

```
def sparse_categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False, axis=-1):
""" ...
"""
...

# Note: tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
# expects logits, Keras expects probabilities.
if not from_logits:
    _epsilon = _to_tensor(epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
    output = tf.clip_by_value(output, _epsilon, 1 - _epsilon)
    output = tf.log(output)
...
```

You could see that if `from_logits` is `False` then `output` value is clipped to `epsilon` and `1-epsilon`.
That means that if the value is slightly changing outside of this bounds the result will not react on it.

However in my knowledge it's quite exotic situation when it really matters.