# What is the activation layer used for TensorFlow text classification example

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, activation-function

I am trying to understand the `TensorFlow` text classification example at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification. They define the model as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1)])
```

To the best of my knowledge, deep learning models use an activation function and I wonder what activation function the above classification model uses internally.
Can anyone help me understand that?

Comment: I don't believe that simple model uses a non-linear activation function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you read, the model definition is written something like this

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1)])
```

And the data set used in [that](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification) tutorials is a **binary classification** `zero` and `one`. By **not defining any activation** to the **last layer** of the model, the original author wants to get the `logits` rather than **probability**. And that why they used the `loss` function as

```
model.compile(loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              ...
```

Now, if we set the last layer activation as `sigmoid` (which usually pick for binary classification), then we must set `from_logits=False`. So, here are two option to chose from:

### with logit: True

We take the `logit` from the last layer and that why we set `from_logits=True`.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1, activation=None)])

model.compile(loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_ds, verbose=2,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs)
```

```
7ms/step - loss: 0.6828 - accuracy: 0.5054 - val_loss: 0.6148 - val_accuracy: 0.5452
Epoch 2/3
7ms/step - loss: 0.5797 - accuracy: 0.6153 - val_loss: 0.4976 - val_accuracy: 0.7406
Epoch 3/3
7ms/step - loss: 0.4664 - accuracy: 0.7734 - val_loss: 0.4197 - val_accuracy: 0.8096
```

### without logit: False

And here we take the `probability` from the last layer and that why we set `from_logits=False`.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])

model.compile(loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_ds, verbose=2,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs)
```

```
Epoch 1/3
8ms/step - loss: 0.6818 - accuracy: 0.6163 - val_loss: 0.6135 - val_accuracy: 0.7736
Epoch 2/3
7ms/step - loss: 0.5787 - accuracy: 0.7871 - val_loss: 0.4973 - val_accuracy: 0.8226
Epoch 3/3
8ms/step - loss: 0.4650 - accuracy: 0.8365 - val_loss: 0.4195 - val_accuracy: 0.8472
```

---

Now, you may wonder, why this tutorial uses `logit` (or no activation to the last layer)? The short answer is, it generally doesn't matter, we can choose any option. The thing is, there is a chance of numerical instability in the case of using `from_logits=False`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61237426/9215780) answer for more details.

Comment: I am interested in enhancing your answer by commenting this part of the tutorial: "Since this is a binary classification problem and the model outputs a probability (a single-unit layer with a sigmoid activation)" + the fact that a sigmoid is used when making predictions.

Comment: I see. I didn't notice their statement there. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks @M.Innat, does this answer applicable for multi class classifier using the same model with `losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` loss function?

Comment: Yes, it applicable for multiclass cases. See [this](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/antirectifier/) example.

Answer (score 0):

This model uses a single [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) at the output (a sigmoid), used for predictions for a **binary classification task**.

The task to perform often guides the choice of both loss and activation functions. In this case, therefore, the [Binary-Cross-Entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) loss function is used, as well as the sigmoid activation function (which is also called the logistic function, and outputs values between 0 and 1 for any real value taken as input). This is quite well explained in [this post](https://medium.com/arteos-ai/the-differences-between-sigmoid-and-softmax-activation-function-12adee8cf322).

In contrast, you can also have multiple activation functions in a neural network, depending on its architecture; it is very common for instance in convolutional neural networks to have an activation function for each convolutional layer, as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn).